# How to enable VT-X when its hidden in BIOS

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, vt-x

I have a Gateway LX6810-01 with a Intel Core TM2 Quad CPU Q8200 processor. I would like to enable VT-X so I can have 64 bit virutalization but the BIOS has hidden the option. I checked for a BIOS update (its AMI v2.64) and could not find one. Does anyone have any suggestions?

I am running VirtualBox on here but can only have 32 bit images, I would like to have a 64 bit image.

Comment: You mean Q8200?

Comment: Correct, the Q8200

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Until you say otherwise, I am going to assume that you are talking about the Q8200.

I have bad news for you: That processor does not have that functionality so you are only going to be able to virtualize 32-bit OS'es. See the matrix linked below:

http://www.intel.com/products/processor/core2quad/specifications.htm

Comment: Thank you for marking the answer even though it was not what you wanted to hear.

Comment: Of course, I would up vote your answer for quick and accurate response, but I do not have 15 reputation points yet.

Comment: @Meyer Denney Thank you, but I am maxed on upvotes for the day anyway (200 is max). I did upvote your question.